# Websocket with spring-boot doesn't work

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, websocket

I have a server in spring-boot that defines a websockt endpoint. When I try to connect to the server with a simple client from noede it gave me the 404 code error.

These is the class that defines the endpoint :

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/websocketEndpoint").withSockJS();
}
}
```

And this is a simple node file that I want to access the endpoint to see if it is a problem with server or with the how I want to access it :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;

var client = new WebSocketClient();

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log("Received: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
        }
    });

    function sendNumber() {
        if (connection.connected) {
            var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
            connection.sendUTF(number.toString());
            setTimeout(sendNumber, 1000);
        }
    }
    sendNumber();
});

client.connect('ws://localhost:8180/websocketEndpoint');
```

I was looking on the endpoint mapping on and the following appear

```
/websocketEndpoint /**      stompWebSocketHandlerMapping
```

So, I don't know exactly why it won't work because I think the endpoint is created. I am also using rabbitmq on the server but it doesn't affect the ws commpunication.

UPDATE:

I try to run this with node client.js

```
Connect Error: Error: Server responded with a non-101 status: 200 
Response Headers Follow:
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
x-frame-options: DENY
x-application-context: application:8180
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 19
date: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 10:40:18 GMT
```

Comment: You have a leading ` ` (whitespace) in your mapping. Remove it or add it in your client.

Comment: It wasn't this problem

Comment: Have you fixed your mappings? If so update your post with it and also what isn't happing? Judging from what is posted here currently the URLs simply don't match. You should have an error on the client side if the connection cannot be established.